# Flex preload states

Tags: apache-flex, performance, adobe

Is it possible to preload the states? So that while a user is browsing say state1, state2 and state3 are loading.

Comment: It would be good if you can provide more data. what do you want to load, or what is the problem?

Comment: I think i was clear enough. Are you a flex expert? I guess you should know what i am talking about. When a state is displayed all the components it has are loaded. This takes cpu time and slows the app down. I want to load the components inside the state while the user is viewing the other states.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is sooo old, but I had the same problem today and I figured it out:

You just have to set the property `itemCreationPolicy="immediate"`